# submitting text with Yii

Tags: php, forms, yii

I'm knew to Yii and am trying to learn some of the more basic functions. I'm using the base application used by Yii, but with my own models. Everything was working up to this point. I'm now trying to add comments to items. I created a widget and I want the button to submit on click the form data, and not bring me to the default create page.

Code used to init widget

```
<?php
    $this->widget('application.components.Comment', array(
        'url'=>'url',
    ));
?>
```

Comment.php

```
<?php
class Comment extends CWidget {

public $comments = array();
public $url = '';

public function run() {
    $model=new AlbumComment;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['AlbumComment']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['AlbumComment'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->comment_Id));
    }
    $this->render('comment', array('url' => $this->url));
}
}?>
```

comment.php

```
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm('Create', 'post', array('id'=>'commentForm')); ?>
<div class='addComment' style='display: block; width: 170px;'>
<div id='commentBanner' style='color: #298dcd; background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #b7d6e7; padding-left: 15px; font-weight: 600; font-size: 12px;'>Write Commit</div>
<?php echo CHtml::textField('comment', '', array('style'=>'height: 25px; width: 164px; margin: 5px 0;'));?>
<?php 
    $id = preg_match('/\d$/', Yii::app()->request->url, $model);
    echo CHtml::textField('commentId', $id, array('style'=>'display:none;'));?>

<?php 
    $pattern = '/\d$/';
    $id = preg_match('/\d$/', Yii::app()->request->url, $model);
    //$url = Yii::app()->createUrl('AlbumComment/Create', array('album_Id'=>$id));
    echo CHtml::button(
    'submit',
    array(
        'submit'=>'components/Comment',
    ));?>
</div>
```

This redirects me to the create page of whatever model I'm on, but I want it to automatically submit the inputted text and save to db for the model I'm on. I hope this is clear enough, and any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I got it to give me the data submitted correctly. The last part is getting it to direct to Comment.php and not the AlbumCommentController.php

I tried:

```
echo CHtml::button(
'submit',
array(
    'submit'=>'components/Comment',
));?>
```

I get: The system is unable to find the requested action "components/Comment". I had 'submit'=>'Comment' but got: The system is unable to find the requested action "Comment".

Any Ideas?

Comment: Could you please tell me an example of `url`?

Comment: url example: http://127.0.0.1/trackstar/yii/framework/trackstar/index.php/artist/1

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the below code always submits form to `Create` page"

```
echo CHtml::button('submit',array('submit' => 'Create'));
```

As Yii's official document says:

> **submit: string, specifies the URL to submit to.** If the current element has a parent form, that form will be submitted, and if 'submit' is non-empty its value will replace the form's URL. If there is no parent form the data listed in 'params' will be submitted instead (via POST method), to the URL in 'submit' or the currently requested URL if 'submit' is empty.

So, you need to change it. On the other hand you must create Yii style urls. For example `ctrl/action` must be written like below:

```
Yii::app()->createUrl('ctrl/action');
```

It is also suggested to use `CHtml` to create form like below:

```
    echo CHtml::beginForm('action', 'post', array('id'=>'commentForm'));
    echo CHtml::textField('comment', '', array('style'=>'height: 25px; width: 164px; margin: 5px 0;'));
    echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit');
    echo CHtml::endForm();
```

Another important note is that you are working with `ActiveRecord` when you are trying to save a record into database. So you must use `ActiveForm` instead or change your input names like `ModelName[AttributeName]`